# fpga_loadbitstream: Wrong bitstream ID for this device...: Bitstream ID xc7z010clg400-1, current device ID 0/7z010

Tags: fpga

I am trying to use f4pga to compile one of their examples in f4pga-examples from verilog into a bitstream and run it on my ZYBO Zynq 7000, following the instructions here:
https://f4pga-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running-examples.html
(Note that I had to substitute "fatload" for "load", as there is no "load".)

```
zynq-uboot> fatload mmc 0 0x10000000 top.bit
reading top.bit
2083847 bytes read in 349 ms (5.7 MiB/s)
zynq-uboot> fpga loadb 0 0x10000000 2083847
  design filename = "/tmp/tmpoyzn0_4q;Generator=xc7frames2bit"
fpga_loadbitstream: Wrong bitstream ID for this device
fpga_loadbitstream: Bitstream ID xc7z010clg400-1, current device ID 0/7z010
fpga - loadable FPGA image support

Usage:
fpga [operation type] [device number] [image address] [image size]
fpga operations:
  dump    [dev]            Load device to memory buffer
  info    [dev]            list known device information
  load    [dev] [address] [size]    Load device from memory buffer
  loadb    [dev] [address] [size]    Load device from bitstream buffer
(Xilinx only)
  loadmk [dev] [address]    Load device generated with mkimage
    For loadmk operating on FIT format uImage address must include
    subimage unit name in the form of addr:<subimg_uname>
zynq-uboot>
```

Ideas?  Could it be as simple as changing the bitstream ID to something else?

Answer (score 0):

The newer uboot (i tested master branch) does not check the device id.
should be not to hard to upgrade, only loading of images changed.
you have to take a look into extlinux and some other enviroment generation.

I could load the old bitstream but when I try a newer one my system hangs,
need more investigation.

br
TuxCoder